# Who are allowed and there is a way to create badges?

Tags: support, badges

Who actually create the badges system? There are ranked users that can do it? May it one day be possible?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**About badges:**

See here for the meta.SO FAQ entry:

> #### [How do "badges" work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17853/how-do-badges-work)
>
> Badges are a way of recognizing users
> who contribute to the website. There
> are many ways to contribute, and
> consequently, there are many badges.
> [...]

Basically, badges are *never* created by users, even high-rep ones. The badges that exist now are more or less fixed, although sometimes there are new badges introduced. I wouldn't expect much to change.

**Letting users create badges:**

There is no sign of being able to create your own badges. I wouldn't really see the point, but if you have a reason why you'd want users to be able to create badges, you should write a feature request on meta. I see you tagged your question with [feature-request](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/feature-request), but note that you should *really* have some good arguments before.

**Getting your own badge idea through:**

Also, you can always write a request on meta for a certain badge you think would be useful. There have been some requests already. Here's an older (but huge) CW with [additional badge ideas](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/102/additional-badge-ideas). Might be hard to come up with anything new after you've read all those!